Doubt in the proof of uniqueness of radial geodesics in a normal neighborhood
I am reading this proof from O'Neil's book Semi-Riemannian Geometry, which is actually also valid for Riemannian manifolds


But I am stuck at the last part, the highlighted contradiction argument which looks wrong and pointless to me.
1 If the author is assuming that the radial segment leaves $\tilde {\mathscr{U}}$, then why does he write $t_0w \in \tilde {\mathscr{U}}$, instead of $ t_0w \notin\tilde {\mathscr{U}}$?Why is $\exp_o(t_0w)\in \mathscr{U}\setminus \tau([0,1])$?
2 I don't see where the contradiction is and what  the point is of proving that that segment does not leave $\tilde{\mathscr{U}}$.
3 (not related to the previous one)What is the point of considering three geodesics ($\tau,\sigma, t\mapsto \exp_o(tw)$)to prove uniqueness instead of only 2 as one normaly does to prove uniqueness of anything?
Could you help me clarify these things ?
